# trying to convert web.xml file into servlet 3.0 format with annotation

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, servlets

Currently, I am learning how to connect my spring project with DB from a book I have. But, in this book, project is written with WEB.xml which is I dont want to use. 
Can you help me to convert this xml file with proper servlet 3.0 format?

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>jdbc.DBCPInitListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>poolConfig</param-name>
    <param-value>
        jdbcdriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/board?characterEncoding=utf8
        dbUser=jspexam
        dbPass=jsppw
        validationQuery=select 1
        minIdle=3
        maxTotal=30
        poolName=board
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I mean with annotations like @WebServletContextListener

Comment: Please don't do this. Having all config in one place is much much better than having partial configs in multiple files. It's true these annotations are very fancy and nice, but doesn't mean they are perfect. Just make sure you don't make conflict by using annotations with web.xml conf file.

Comment: oh so you mean its better to have web.xml conf file rather than remove it and replace with annotation? I thought it is recommended NOT to use web.xml

Comment: I really don't know if it's really recommended to not use `web.xml`, but as my experience, when you omit web.xml, later you might face with issues like path conflict, duplicate names, etc. so now checking stuffs in one file is much much easier than over +100 code file! But it's all about your taste, if you liek to go for annotation way, go for it dear.